# I applied for a job at another company and someone from that company forwarded my job application to the manager at my current company

Tags: job-search, united-states

I applied for a job at another company and, unbeknownst to me, the person reviewing resumes at that other company (let's call them person A) is friends with the owner of my current company (let's call them person B). So person A then forwards person B my job application, telling them that I'm looking for other jobs. Now I'm hearing, on the grapevine, that person B wants to let me go for being disloyal, for having one foot out the door already, etc.

Obviously, I no longer want to work for the other company, but it's still most annoying that my current job is now in jeopardy because of information was being unethically (and maybe illegally?) shared.

If I do get let go because of this would I have grounds for a wrongful termination suit? How would this factor into my application for unemployment?

What recourse do I have?

I'm in [Texas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas), United States, if that matters.

Comment: Criticise all of them on glassdoor. But, watch out for your NDAs.

Comment: withdraw the application from the new job if you don't you might end up without either of the jobs and also after withdrawing find a new job somewhere safe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your employer can fire you at any time since Texas has [at-will employment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-will_employment).  You would not be able to sue them if they did, but would be able to file for and collect unemployment.

As for the recruiter, they would only be liable if there were any confidentiality agreement in place, which would be uncommon.

Your best bet is to slag the heck out of the second company on [Glassdoor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glassdoor) on general principle and then, if your current company does end up firing you, slag the heck out of them too (though they may try to give you severance for a nondisparagement agreement to prevent this).   You could also complain to both companies' HR departments just to make trouble for the two managers if you've been fired anyway (I would not do this if you're not fired as it will definitely get you fired).

Comment: Person B (at his current company) is the owner. I don’t think complaining to HR will make trouble for them.

Answer (score 7):

> What recourse do I have?

None, unless you have a binding employment contract or are terminated for a reason that's legally prohibited (like terminating you because you're Hispanic, or disabled, or female, etc.). Texas is an "at-will" state, meaning:

***absent a statute or an express agreement (such as an employment contract) to the contrary, either party in an employment relationship may modify any of the terms or conditions of employment, or terminate the relationship altogether, for any reason, or no particular reason at all, with or without advance notice.***